# Record delimeter issue with \u00c3 while text processing in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, utf-8, iso-8859-1, csv

I have data like below in .R101206 file(text).
2019-07-15 13:35:21 34567890 General NÃ
2019-07-15 13:35:21 34567891 General1 NÃ
2019-07-15 13:35:21 34567892 General2 NÃ

I'm trying to read the file with delimiter "**\u00C3\u000A**" (ÃLF) by using Spark like below, but it always returns count 1.

```
val path = "/filepath/file1.R011206"
val recDelimiter = "\u00c3\u000a"
var conf = spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration
conf.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter", recDelimiter)
val rawRDD = spark
.sparkContext
.newAPIHadoopFile(path, classOf[TextInputFormat], classOf[LongWritable], classOf[Text], conf)
.map(_._2.toString)
rawRDD.count()
```

Output: res180: Long = 1

We can ignore Ã (Latin A with a tilde) but I need to get the records by using this delimiter since we have Line Feed(LF) in the content of one of the field value. Hence I'm trying to read the records with this delimiter to differentiate records.
Could you please help me how can read it correctly?

Comment: Could you please provide the sample data of text file .R011206 in pre-formatted string?
The current data is in a single line and the char after Ã seems to be a space instead of the claimed LF. Due to this its hard to produce the issue.

Comment: We have Line Feed for every record after Ã. It looked like "ÃLF". And it's not in a single line.

Comment: Finally, I'm able to get each record from the file by using sc.binaryFiles.
Here is the code block.
val rawRDD = sparkSession.sparkContext.binaryFiles(path)
              .mapValues(content => new String(content.toArray(), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1.toString))
              .map(_._2.toString)
              .flatMap(_.split("\u00c3\u000a",-1))
              .map(x => (path,x))

Answer (score 1):

I think your uncode for `Ã` is wrong.

```
val recDelimiter = "\u00c3\u000a"
println("Ã" == recDelimiter) 
//false

for (line <- Source.fromFile(path).getLines()) {
    println(line.contains(recDelimiter))
    //false
}
```

```
val recDelimiter = "\u00c3"
println("Ã" == recDelimiter) 
//true

var conf = spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration
conf.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter", recDelimiter)

val rawRDD = spark
  .sparkContext
  .newAPIHadoopFile(path, classOf[TextInputFormat], classOf[LongWritable], classOf[Text], conf)
  .map(_._2.toString)
println(rawRDD.count()) //3
```

Comment: In each record, we have Ã with Line Feed(LF). So I have added "\u00c3\u000a". Anyway, I tried with "\u00c3" but the same issue exists.

Comment: Also, I can see "▒" in place of "Ã" when I get the first lines of records in Git bash.

Comment: Which Spark version do you use? With 2.4.3 the above worked for me I got `3` rows.

Comment: I'm using Zepplin to test this. The spark version is 2.2.0. If I modified the file and save it, then I got the 3 rows. But if we try with the original file, I'm not able to get the records with that delimiter.

Comment: Finally, I'm able to get each record from the file by using sc.binaryFiles.
Here is the code block.
val rawRDD = sparkSession.sparkContext.binaryFiles(path)
              .mapValues(content => new String(content.toArray(), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1.toString))
              .map(_._2.toString)
              .flatMap(_.split("\u00c3\u000a",-1))
              .map(x => (path,x))